# Статистика температуры видеокарты

Tags: windows, windows-10, железо, поиск-программ, видеокарта

Нужна программа для замера и сохранения статистики по температуре видеокарты.

Единственное требование - нужен не только мониторинг в реальном времени, а сохранение данных и возможность их последующего просмотра. Дело в том, что собираюсь установить в корпус ssd, которое будет расположено довольно близко к видеокарте и потенциально будет мешать её охлаждению (а может ещё и само её дополнительно греть будет). Хотелось бы иметь графики температуры до установки и после, чтобы понимать, есть ли какие-то последствия и насколько они существенны.

Программ для мониторинга в реальном времени вроде бы много, а вот какие из них способны сохранять или показывать историю?

Интересуют бесплатные как минимум для личного использования программы.

Comment: msi afterburner. опция типа Log history to file. А вообще вы не по адресу, тут люди кодингом занимаются

Comment: @Sergey Tatarincev, да у нас не только про кодинг.

Comment: Тебе, я так понимаю, для Windows? Стоит уточнить в вопросе.

Comment: NVidia/AMD/Intel дискретная, интегрированная, ПК или ноутбук? (да-да, почти очевидно, что ПК и дискретная, но все же). Тоже может повлиять на ответ.

Comment: Google показал, что в GPU-Z есть continuous monitoring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848828/8086115.

Comment: @eanmos, да, Windows 10.

Comment: @Kromster, Nvidia (а почему это важно?), дискретная, десктоп.

Comment: Можно поступить как очень большие дядьки и воткнуть zabbix. Правда я хз есть ли там шаблоны для видюх, но наверное должно быть, раз есть хостинг с видюхами.